# Removable media mounts as read-only filesystem

Tags: permissions, mount

I having a recurring issue with removable media such as HDD's failing to mount properly, which slows me down quite  a bit.  I've fixed it in the past but then the issue comes back with the same devices and I'm stuck again trying to resolve the issue.  In this case, I ran the command

`cat /proc/mounts | grep -i ro`
and saw
`/dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb-WD_My_Book_(...)-0:0-part2 hfsplus ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8 0 0

I then tried to run `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb2`
but this did not change the result.  I have tried to use chown and chmod with no luck, either.  What is going on to make this the deafult behavior of the OS?

Comment: Have you scanned the messages and looked at why it's being mounted RO. The most common issue is errors are detected, and thus a RW mount is flipped RO to prevent data loss, and messages appear in logs giving this detail. Scan your logs.  (*You've provided no specifics as to OS & release, so this detail is generic*)

Comment: Note the "`uid=0,gid=0`" - it's owned by `[root:root]`. Try `-o remount,rw,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)`